# Given a number compute its fibonacci-ish series

Tags: algorithm

Lets assume you are given a number. You have to compute its `fibonacci-ish` sequence. For example, we all know the fibonacci sequence 
`0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ......`.

If were to give you the number 21, you would have to print the sequence `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21`

Now consider another number 26. Its not in the sequence above. But there  is one sequence. That is `0 2 2 4 6 10 16 26`.

Consider another one. 7. The sequence is `1 3 4 7`.

Notice for every number there can be multiple sequences. For example, you could've said 26 falls in sequence `1 25 26`.

You have to maximize the sequence. By maximizing I mean that you have to find the maximum amount of numbers in the sequence. For example, `1 25 26` has only 3 numbers whereas `0 2 2 4 6 10 16 26` has 8 numbers. So the sequence with 8 numbers is preferable.

So, the problem statement is `Given a number compute its series of numbers where the sequence has maximum amount of numbers`.

Approach that I tried:

Checking number for every values. For example for 26, the sequence can be

26 25 1 
26 24 2 
26 23 3 
26 22 4 
26 21 5 
26 20 6 
26 19 7 
and so on.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Nice. I don't understand what is it that we're maximizing. What exactly is the problem statement?

Comment: Is there no restriction on the first number?

Comment: I assume by "maximize the sequence" you mean "maximize the **length** of the sequence". And these aren't fibonacci-series. They only follow the rules of a fibonacci-sequence in a few restricted ways. E.g. they don't start with `0 1 1`. You should provide a more precise definition of how the sequences are built. But an interesting problem as far as I understand it.

Comment: I've modified the statement. please check again @blazs. There is no restriction on first number. Yes you are right paul.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? please specify a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start from a pair other than 1,1 then the ratio between successive terms is still approximately (1 + sqrt(5))/2.  To find the longest sequence that ends with n choose the next largest number to be either the floor or ceiling of n * (sqrt(5) - 1) / 2, then run the fibonacci sequence backwards.

For example starting with 21, we have 21 * (sqrt(5)-1) /2 = 12.98, so
using 13 we run backwards  to get  8 = 21 - 13, 5 = 13 - 8, 3, 2 , 1, 1

with 26 we get the next number being 16, giving the reverse sequence
26, 16, 10, 6, 4, 2, 2, 0

Comment: Amazing @deinst. But I dont understand the fact why using (1 + sqrt(5))/2 yields the right answer? Any proof of that?

Comment: @S_kar It is true of the usual fibonacci series, (google will give you thousands of references).  If you start with a, b, then you get a +b, a+2b, 2a+3b, 3a+5b, ... .  The coefficients are just consecutive fibonacci numbers, and since the ratio of consecutive fibonacci numbers is nearly phi, so is the the ratio of the generalized sequence, and the longer the sequence the closer the ratio.